# Send multiple package shipment to fedex in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, fedex

I am trying to pass multiple package weight in **app/code/local/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php** , when the shipping package weight is greater than **150 Lbs**. Currently it showing **Freight** charges if package weight is greater than 150 Lbs. What I am trying to do is whenever the package weight is more than 150 Lbs for ex.- 374 Lbs, Then the weight will divide into smaller packages like (150 , 150 , 74). And that's the way to avoid freight charges in fedex shippment.

After some debugging I found that weight is passing in request like this in my fedex.php file.

`<?php $ratesRequest = array(
            'WebAuthenticationDetail' => array(
                'UserCredential' => array(
                    'Key'      => $r->getKey(),
                    'Password' => $r->getPassword()
                )
            ),
            'ClientDetail' => array(
                'AccountNumber' => $r->getAccount(),
                'MeterNumber'   => $r->getMeterNumber()
            ),
            'Version' => $this->getVersionInfo(),
            'RequestedShipment' => array(
                'DropoffType'   => $r->getDropoffType(),
                'ShipTimestamp' => date('c'),
                'PackagingType' => $r->getPackaging(),
                'TotalInsuredValue' => array(
                    'Amount'  => $r->getValue(),
                    'Currency' => $this->getCurrencyCode()
                ),
                'Shipper' => array(
                    'Address' => array(
                        'PostalCode'  => $r->getOrigPostal(),
                        'CountryCode' => $r->getOrigCountry()
                    )
                ),
                'Recipient' => array(
                    'Address' => array(
                        'PostalCode'  => $r->getDestPostal(),
                        'CountryCode' => $r->getDestCountry(),
                        'Residential' => (bool)$this->getConfigData('residence_delivery')
                    )
                ),
                'ShippingChargesPayment' => array(
                    'PaymentType' => 'SENDER',
                    'Payor' => array(
                        'AccountNumber' => $r->getAccount(),
                        'CountryCode'   => $r->getOrigCountry()
                    )
                ),
                'CustomsClearanceDetail' => array(
                    'CustomsValue' => array(
                        'Amount' => $r->getValue(),
                        'Currency' => $this->getCurrencyCode()
                    )
                ),
                'RateRequestTypes' => 'LIST',
                'PackageCount'     => '1',
                'PackageDetail'    => 'INDIVIDUAL_PACKAGES',
                'RequestedPackageLineItems' => array(
                    '0' => array(
                        'Weight' => array(
                            'Value' => $weight,
                            'Units' => 'LB'
                        ),
                        'GroupPackageCount' => 1
                    )
                )
            )
        ); ?>`

and array of multiple package weight which I'm getting is like -

`<?php 
Array(
[0] => 150,
[1] => 150,
[2] => 74
) ?>`

But not getting how can I pass this array of multiple weight in Fedex weight.

Please help me to do this. Any suggestion would be appreciate.